# Add the number of descendants for each li node

Tags: javascript, dom

A web page has a nested list.  The goal is to insert the number of descendants for each li node (except for leaf nodes).

Here is an example of the expected output:

```
Animals [9]
    Mammals [4]
        Cows
        Donkeys
        Dogs
        Tigers
    Other [3]
        Snakes
        Birds
        Lizards
Fishes [5]
    Aquarium [2]
        Guppy
        Angelfish
    Sea [1]
        Sea trout
```

Here is the javascript I wrote:

```
function isLeaf(elem) {
    if(elem.firstElementChild === null) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}

function countDescendants(elem) {
    if(isLeaf(elem)) return 0;

    else {
        let children = elem.firstElementChild.children;
        let count = 0;

        for(let child of children) {
            if(isLeaf(child)) {
                   count++;
            }

            else {
                count = count + 1 + countDescendants(child);
            }

        }
        return count;
    }
}

function insertCount(elem) {
    let count = countDescendants(elem);
    let text = elem.firstChild.textContent.trim();
    text = text + " [" + count + "]";
    elem.firstChild.textContent = text;
}

function traverseDOM(root) {
    let children = root.children;

    for(let child of children) {
        if(!isLeaf(child)) {
            if(child.tagName === "LI") {
                insertCount(child);
            }
            traverseDOM(child);
        }
    }
}

//traverse DOM tree
//try catch is for debugging only
try {
    if(document.body.firstElementChild !== null) {
        traverseDOM(document.body.firstElementChild);
    }
}  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

The code works.  I get this nagging feeling it could be done better.  For example, is there a way to improve the countDescendants function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think functional coding style is best suited here, because it will significantly reduce amount of code. Also, you will have clearly separated structure consisting of functions with single responsibility.

### Suggested solution

```
function insertCounts(root) {
    forEachElement(root, (el) => el.innerHTML = countText(count(el)) + el.innerHTML, el => !isLeaf(el) && (el.tagName === 'LI'));
}

function countText(count) {
     return `[${count}]`;
}

function forEachElement(root, apply, predicate = () => true) {
    Array.from(root.children).forEach(el => { predicate(el) && apply(el); forEachElement(el, apply, predicate) });
}

function count(root) {
    return Array.from(root.children).reduce((acc, el) => isLeaf(el) ? acc + 1 : acc + count(el), 0);
}

function isLeaf(elem) {
    return (elem.firstElementChild === null);
}


try {
    if(document.body.firstElementChild !== null) {
        insertCounts(document.body.firstElementChild);
    }
}  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Just wow. This solution shows the difference between a pro and a novice. Using Array.from is clever. I absolutely agree that each function should only do one task. Couple of questions though. In the forEachElement function why have `predicate = () => true`? I mean if I change it to `predicate` I get the same output.

Comment: Also I want to display the count after the text and not before. I changed the insertCount function to this: `function insertCounts(root) {   forEachElement(root, el => el.firstChild.textContent = el.firstChild.textContent.trim() + countText(count(el)), el => !isLeaf(el) && (el.tagName === 'LI')); }` It works but is there a better way?

Comment: `predicate = () => true`: this is just default value for a parameter. I just thinking that usual call of this function will be with two arguments, that's why I made default third one. In this particular case we have only one call of function `forEachElement()` and we pass third argument, so default value is redundant.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see better way to change text content than yours.